# WebView in fragments

Tags: java, android, webview

I am creating an application for android and I need to put a webview in a fragment but I have tried a lot of codes and none works for me. I need help

This is the code of my fragment When I run the application with that code in the fragment is when it stops.

I do not know if it will be for the code that brings the default fragment since all the menu sections work but when I enter this one that has a webview it stops

```
    package org.protectorabaix;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link ListadoAnimales.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link ListadoAnimales#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class ListadoAnimales extends Fragment {

    public WebView mWebView;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public ListadoAnimales() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ListadoAnimales.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ListadoAnimales newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ListadoAnimales fragment = new ListadoAnimales();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listado_animales, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.listado);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return v;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code would be useful. Show us what you've tried, and your current code. It's tricky to find the issue with your code out of nowhere.

Comment: @jdstaerk In a little I upload it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Displaying WebView in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306140/android-displaying-webview-in-fragment)

Comment: @jdstaerk I tried that code and the application stops when entering that fragment in the navigation

Comment: Yeah. That's information we need. What is the exception?

Comment: @jdstaerk i added the code

Comment: @jdstaerk you can help me?