# Android Studio Webview in a Fragment shows nothing and empty

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-webview

I wish to implement a webview in the fragment_home_screen without covering the BottomNavigationView. However, even I followed everything on an online tutorial by setting up the webview in the Fragment_Home.java onCreateView() method. Nothing has showed up. I tried adding a button in the fragment_home_screen.xml to ensure the fragment DID showed up. It ended up showing the BUTTON ONLY.
I have been trying to fix this issues for hours and still couldn't figuring what's wrong with my code. Got any idea?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.exercise.myApplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Map"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Login"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_SignUp"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Home"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Main" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity_Home.java**

```
package android.exercise.myApplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class Activity_Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectFragment = null;
                    switch(item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.homeScreen:
                            selectFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.userScreen:
                            selectFragment = new Fragment_User();
                            break;
                        case R.id.driverScreen:
                            selectFragment = new Fragment_Driver();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };


}
```

**Fragment_Home.java**

```
package android.exercise.myApplication;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link Fragment_Home#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public Fragment_Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Fragment_Home.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Fragment_Home newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragment_Home fragment = new Fragment_Home();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String url = "https://pastebin.com/";
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_screen, container, false);

        WebView myWebview = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebview.loadUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/");
        myWebview.setWebViewClient(
                new SSLWebViewClient()
        );

        myWebview.clearView();
        myWebview.measure(100, 100);
        myWebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        return v;
    }

}
```

**activity_main_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity_Home" >

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/fragment_container"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_home_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragment_Home">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </WebView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/webview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/webview" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**As for the logcat, filtered with warnings there's only one line of error:**

> 022-01-19 21:45:53.557 7053-7053/android.exercise.myApplication E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: `clearView` is deprecated use webview.loadUrl("about:blank") instead. Can you clear your `WebView` code and test with only `loadUrl` as a starting point? Also can you link the tutorial?

Comment: your code works fine I tried them and shows web content. Please, check your emulator/device internet connection before testing otherwise inside code everything looks fine.

Comment: @RudraRokaya Thanks for your time in testing my code. If someting is wrong with my emulator is there any way I can check to see if there's errors in the device?

Comment: I also tried with 3 seperate emulators but i dont see anything showed up in the fragment_home_screen but Buttons i placed previously.

Comment: @AliasCartellano I added excessive code to see if the webview could work. This is the tutorial i looked for 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37306218/15057418

Comment: @RudraRokaya **Update**: I even tried with my real android device the same thing happened.

Comment: I tested your code on API level 30 one plus nord n100 real device and it does show your web content.

Comment: myWebview.setWebViewClient(
                new SSLWebViewClient()
        ); can you comment out this part. and try again.

Comment: @RudraRokaya OMG!!! It finally works. You're my lifesaver!!! Thank you.

Comment: welcome. Happy to help.

Comment: if that helps you, accept as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it works fine you just need to comment out some code in  **Fragment_Home.java**  as below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(....){
  .....
  ..........
 //remove or comment this part.
 // myWebView.setWebViewClient(new SSLWebViewClient()); 
 .....
}
```